# Beginner C programming passing pointers to function is giving unpredicted result

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am learning C as a part of my curriculum, and I am still learning the concepts of pointers. The following example gives unpredicted results for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Calculate(int *x, int *y, int *k, int *m) {
k = *x * *y;
m = *x + *y;
}

int main() {
int *k;
int *m;
int g = 10;
int h = 11;
Calculate(&g, &h, k, m);
printf("%d\n", m);
printf("%d", k);
}
```

Each execution is giving me different results, like

```
-1155180448
0
```

or

```
253276384
0
```

or
    591649904
    0

but if I change the code to

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Calculate(int *x, int *y, int *k, int *m) {
*k = *x * *y;
*m = *x + *y;
}

int main() {
int k;
int m;
int g = 10;
int h = 11;
Calculate(&g, &h, &k, &m);
printf("%d\n", m);
printf("%d", k);
```

}

it prints the correct values like

```
21
110
```

Isn't using `int *k; int *m;` and passing it to a function as `somefunc(k, m)` the same as `int k; int m; somefunc(&k, &m)`?

Kindly explain what is wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: Your main problem here is that you don't compile your programs with warnings enabled. If you do you will get some clues. Don't expect the program to work as expected until it compiles cleanly (with no warnings).

Comment: You can not dereference an uninitialized pointer: `k` and `m`, turn warnings on.

Comment: @AlterMann Thank you, and please forgive my ignorance, isn't `k = *x * *y;` inside the function considered an initialization?

Comment: No, you are assigning to a local variable, the lifetime of this variable ends with the function, furthermore, you can not assign the result of x * y to a pointer.

Comment: @AlterMann So I am actually printing  some variable that is not owned by the program itself? If so, shouldn't the program segfault instead of printing some memory owned not by self? And thank you for taking time to help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer you can read at a memory location that it is not allowed to access and a segfault occurs.

Comment: @AlterMann It is not segfaulting either. That's why I was confused. And your answer you posted a while before, with `void Calculate(int *x, int *y, int **k, int **m) ` worked, eventhough I couldn't understand why it worked. Could you kindly post it as an answer with an explanation that could help me understand, I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: I will try, wait a minute

Comment: Perhaps leaning to use a debugger will reap rewards in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to test this call `Calculate(&g, &h, k, m);` as in your first example, *passing* integers `g` and `h` and integer pointers `*k` and `*m`, first make sure that the pointers *really point at something*, so they can be treated likewise as addresses of integer variables by your `Calculate()` function, or whichever function of syntax alike.

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>  //add this header for malloc

void Calculate(int *x, int *y, int *k, int *m) {
  *k = *x * *y;
  *m = *x + *y;
}

int main() 
{
  int *k = malloc(sizeof(int)); //initialize the pointer to point at something
  int *m = malloc(sizeof(int)); //initialize the pointer to point at something
  int g = 10;
  int h = 11;
  Calculate(&g, &h, k, m);
  printf("%d\n", *m);
  printf("%d\n", *k);
  free(k);    //free the space pointed to by pointers!
  free(m);
return 0;
}
```

This is not a very practical solution (at least as your example is concerned), but is here only to show how you should treat your pointers as function arguments *from within your caller function*.

Comment: `int ki; int * k = &ki;` would be a bit simpler. And `int *k = malloc(sizeof *k);` would be nicer ... ;-)

Comment: That's nicer for sure, @alk, thanks, but wouldn't show so much distinction between an `int` and an `int*`. I added a sentence though… (-:

Comment: Thanks @user3078414. However, instead of initializing it in heap using `int *k = malloc(sizeof(int));`, isn't there a way to initialize it in stack?

Comment: Please, take a look at the following answer, or your example #2. That  is the most elegant way unless you plan modifying values of the input variables inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

The function should be:

```
void Calculate(int *x, int *y, int *k, int *m) {
    *k = *x * *y;
    *m = *x + *y;
}
```

`*k` means an `int` stored in memory being pointed to by `k`. You don't want to modify `k`, you want to modify what is stored in the space `k` points to.

Then you call like this:

```
int a, b;
int g = 10;
int h = 11;
Calculate(&g, &h, &a, &b);
```

You tell the `Calculate` function whereabouts in memory the variables `a` and `b` are which will hold the result of the calculation.

Note: I used different variable names because it is confusing to use the same name `k` for an `int` in one place, and `k` for an `int *` in another place. Another plan of course would be to use `k,m` in `main` and use `pk` or `pm` in the function (meaning "pointer to `k`", etc.)

Also you don't need to use pointers to pass `g` and `h` and in fact this is a bad idea, unless you are planning to change those in the function too.